# List of Acronyms for Text Mining

Tags: text, data-mining

I'm trying to do some text mining and my sample text has a lot of acronyms in it. I would like to try to flatten the acronyms into the phrases. 
Does anyone know where I can get a list? http://www.acronymslist.com is a pretty awesome site and I was looking for something that just had an open list I could download.

Thanks,

mj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_acronyms_and_initialisms

Wikipedia content is freely reusable, subject to the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License.